# Vuex вынесение в геттеры

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

Всем привет,не получается вынести в геттеры небольшой функционал,подскажите как правильно это сделать
Вот такая функция в компоненте

```
 methods: {
    fillDamages(num) {
      for(let ind in this.info.components) {
        if(this.info.components[ind].id == num) {
          this.info.components[ind].active = true;
          this.selected = this.info.components[ind];
          this.current = ind;
        } else {
          this.info.components[ind].active = false;
        }
      }
    },
    nextDamage() {
      let last = this.info.components.length - 1;

      this.info.components.map(item =>{
        if(item.id === this.selected.id && this.message){
          this.$set(item,'comment',this.message);
        }
      });
      this.message = '';

      if(this.current < last) {
        this.info.components[this.current].save = true;
        this.current++;
        for(let comp of this.info.components) {
            comp.active = false;
        }
        this.info.components[this.current].active = true;
        this.selected = this.info.components[this.current];
      } else {
        this.info.components[this.current].save = true;
        this.$router.push('/infocar')
      }
    },
```

И вот тут она используется

```
 <v-btn
            v-model="next"
            @click="nextDamage"
            class="btn-see"
            color="red">Далее</v-btn>
```

И тут

```
<v-card
          v-on:click.native="fillDamages(component.id)"
          v-for="component in info.components"
          :key="component.id"
          tabindex="1"
          class="item">
          <h3>{{component.serialNumber}} . {{component.name}}</h3>
          <v-icon v-if="component.comment" class="icon-damage" color="green">check_circle</v-icon>
        </v-card>
```

Вот как я пытаюсь сделать

```
import axios from 'axios'
export default {
  state:{
    info:[]
  },
  actions: {
    setDamages ({ commit }) {
      axios.get('api/v1/inspection/script', {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('user-token')}`
        },
      }).then(response => {
        commit('setDamages', response.data)
      });
    },
    loadFile({commit},file){
      axios.post('api/v1/files/create', {count: 1},{headers:{Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('user-token')}`},})
        .then(() => axios.put('api/v1/files', file,{headers: {
          'content-type': 'multipart/form-data',
          Authorization:`Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('user-token')}`
        }}));
    },
  },
  mutations: {
    setDamages (state, payload) {
      state.info = payload
    }
  },
  getters: {
    nextDamages: (state) => (next) => {
      let last = this.info.components.length - 1;

      this.info.components.find(item =>{
        if(item.id === this.selected.id && this.message){
          this.$set(item,'comment',this.message);
        }
      });
      this.message = '';

      if(this.current < last) {
        this.info.components[this.current].save = true;
        this.current++;
        for(let comp of this.info.components) {
          comp.active = false;
        }
        this.info.components[this.current].active = true;
        this.selected = this.info.components[this.current];
      } else {
        this.info.components[this.current].save = true;
        this.$router.push('/infocar')
      }
    }
  }
}
```

в компоненте

```
nextDamage() {
      return this.$store.getters.nextDamages(this.next)
    },
            <v-btn
            v-model="next"
            @click="nextDamage"
            class="btn-see"
            color="red">Далее</v-btn>
```

Comment: А что в getter то нужно вынести? Или Вы хотите вынести methods в actions для store?

Comment: Все,что в methods

Comment: Вынести это в геттеры стора,могу показать как я делаю,но я что-то не так делаю)

Comment: Но гетеры это же то что возвращает данные, Вам по видимому вместо них нужны действия, которые вызвут мутации, вместо того чтобы менять данные внутри компонента они будут менять данные внутри state через мутации

Comment: Эмм,не знаю,мне ментор сказал в геттеры вынести(

Comment: В экшенах у меня только запросы к api лежат

Comment: У вас же эти методы в click, если подумать то зачем в click вставлять то что просто должно возвращать данные?)

Comment: Даже не знаю,я еще только учусь)

Comment: И вот сделать не получается(

Comment: Вам нужно вызвать действия для api и в этих действиях записать данные в состояние(state) через мутации. Дальше Вам нужно перенести ваши функции которые в methods в actions и чтобы они работали с state, а не компонентом. Понимаю что для новичка сложно звучит, но что поделать, разбирайтесь по немногу, все таки это опыт на всю жизнь будет)

Comment: Я вот как пытался сделать,посмотрите,я просто даже не представляю как эта функция будет выглядеть в экшенах

Comment: Добавил еще код в вопрос

Comment: А можно ли как-то вынести это в мутации,и присвоить к переменной?

Comment: Я не понял в чем смысл nextDamages если он даже данные не возвращает, также можете использовать mapActions и mapGetters

Comment: А можете все таки показать пожалуйста?

Comment: Помню я вам отвечал [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/875158/vuex-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-store). Пробуйте сами, а то так всю жизнь будете просить, пока сами не научитесь делать